# Are there any sure-fire ways to beat Round 100 on Deflation mode?

Tags: bloons-td-6

There is an achievement for beating Round 100 on Deflation mode. A long time ago, there was a glitch that allowed players to earn money in Deflation mode, but that has since been patched. There are still probably glitched I could use to earn money, but they are really time-consuming.

My highest round is 95 on Cubism with Sauda. When Sauda was added, she was OP. I took advantage of that for sure. I know she can easily solo all the way up to Round 100 in a regular game, but that's with money and early level-ups. That's not possible in Deflation.

[image: Screenshot of my highest round]

On this round, the DDTs overwhelm her.

Are there any strategies, preferably glitchless, that could ensure a win? Not specifically with my current setup, but with any map and any hero?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search of "bloons 6 deflation 100" there seem to be quite a few videos and links to users providing an answer,
One such is [this reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/btd6/comments/94ivn7/deflation_round_100_guide_with_no_powers_no/), where the user goes in depth about how to complete the task with no powers used, but still using monkey knowledge (strategy outlined below).
I'll try this myself later tonight to confirm that it works, but with how detailed it is, it seems valid.

1. Place a (0-0-2) Monkey Village on the RIGHTMOST corner of the leftmost middle square. Placement is important or else you will not be able to fit the 4 Druid of Wrath in the rest of the box. Every tower you place from now on should be under the price reduction from the village.
2. Place Gwyn on the LEFTMOST corner of the leftmost middle square. Placement is important or else you will not be able to fit the 4 Druid of Wrath in the rest of the box.
3. Place 4 Druid of Wrath (0-1-3) in the middle left square. Place the three on the bottom first, and then squeeze the fourth in between Gwen and the village. If your placement of Gwen and the village is not precise, the fourth Druid of Wrath will not fit and you will need to restart the attempt from Step 1.
4. Place 3 Monkey Alchemists right above Gwen and the village in a row. For the leftmost alchemist, make it a (0-3-2) alchemist for the unstable concoction and faster throwing upgrades to ensure that most if not all MOAB class bloons get hit with unstable concoction. Make the middle alchemist a (4-2-0) alchemist for the stronger stimulant (honestly this could be 4-0-0 and it would work just the same), and make the rightmost alchemist a (3-0-0) alchemist for the berserker brew.
5. Set every tower's targeting priority to strong EXCEPT for the top middle Druid of Wrath. Set that one to First, as he is the most likely to be buffed by the two alchemists since he is the closest to them and will be able to most effectively clear out the ceramics that leak from MOABS as the other Druid of Wrath focus on stripping the MOABS down to ceramics.
6. For Rounds 33, 36, 37, you will leak camos. This is necessary as leaking camos will maximize the attack speed of the Druid of Wraths. You will not survive the camo whites if you do not have Mana Shield, so use Gwen's Cocktail of Fire ability when they come if you lack Mana Shield. This would be the only time you would need to use an ability if you lack that particular upgrade, which isn't to big of a deal as you need to stop after round 37 to replace the (0-0-2) village anyways. After Round 37, sell the (0-0-2) village and replace it with a (2-2-0) village.
7. Sit back and let the game auto play to Round 100! I bought a (0-1-0) dart monkey with my leftover 85 cash, and fun fact, he had a pop count of over 20,000 by Round 100. To make sure that you bought the correct upgrades in the correct order, check to see that you have 0 money leftover at the end if you have both cashback Monkey Knowledges.

If you lack the either the starting cash or sellback upgrades from the Monkey Knowledge, you can choose to make the (4-2-0) alchemist a (4-0-0) alchemist, and if you still lack cash after that, make the (0-3-2) alchemist a (0-3-0) alchemist. I would recommend not making the alchemist a (0-3-0) if you can help it as the faster potion reload speed helps greatly with destroying MOAB clusters, especially on rounds 96 and 98. Alternatively, you can make the alchemists into a (0-3-2), a (4-0-2), and a (0-0-1) which is what you would be able to afford with no additional cashback from Monkey Knowledge.